# Баланс нагрузки с HAProxy: как расчитать минимальное железо?

Tags: highload, производительность, сервер, железо

Как расчитать минимальное железо сервера, единственной задачей которого будет балансировать нагрузку с помощью [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)? Т.е. через него будет проходить уйма пакетов - весь трафик популярного сайта.

Например, какой выбрать процессор из XEON'ов: X3430 или E5506? Первый дешевле, и чуть выше производительность по тестам, но нет HyperThreading. Оперативка: 2, 4 8 или 64 гига, не меньше?

Хотя бы намекните по опыту своему, куда копать в определении железа заранее, без возможность поставить варианты и А и Б и померять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz

24Gb

На нем работает как раз Haproxy, запросов ОЧЕНЬ много, работает с среднем LA ~2-3, не жалуюсь.Тьфу-тьфу-тьфу.

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз такой конфиг - один из вариантов на iCertified, где всё происходит. "Очень" много — это сколько? И что там важнее - количество пакетов или объем трафика? Насколько востребована оперативка - с 4Gb станет в 6 раз тяжелее, как думаете?

Comment: Точное количество запросов сложно сказать, но вот по двум шардам mysql около 400 в сек. Оперативка на мой взгляд и как показывает практика не очень востребован для проксирования трафика, у нас ее много не для этих задач) Тут в основном процессорные мощности, + чем лучше работает сеть тем лучше. А так конкретных требований не замечал. По поводу объема трафика, это легко разруливается сегментацией, так что это не критерий.